# Vagrant box_check_update error

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I try to use a `Vagrant` environment. I have `Vagrantfile` and every other needs. I use `Vagrant 1.4.3` version on `Ubuntu 12.04.03`.
After `vagrant up` get following errors.

```
vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: box_check_update
* The box 'ubuntu/vivid64' could not be found.
```

I've checked my `Vagrantfile`, and see `config.vm.box_check_update = false`.
`Ubuntu/vivid64` is here: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/vivid64

Comment: could you share entire Vagrantfile

Comment: @lebobbi: Here is it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13218649/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.vm.box_check_update` and `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/vivid64"` are features of vagrant 1.5 (see blog announcement https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/vagrant-1-5-and-vagrant-cloud.html and https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-boxes-2-0.html)

upgrade to **Vagrant 1.5** (or better latest version) and it will run fine.

Comment: That is okay, but how to update? Because when I have installed most recent version of `Virtualbox`, it says, isn't compatible with `Vagrant`. So how should I map needed version numbers of two environments?

Comment: hum . where do you see that ? [doc](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/index.html) points that its compatible with VirtualBox up to 5.0.x

Comment: I have used now `.deb` packages, that seems solved the problem. Thanks!